# What is wrong with this if-statement?

Tags: perl

I have this code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $nis = "qqq";
my $grp = "pre-qqq";

if ($nis eq $grp || 'pre-' . $nis eq $grp) {
    print "match1\n";
}

if (($nis || 'pre-' . $nis) eq $grp) {
    print "match2\n";
}
```

where the first `if`-statement works, but the second doesn't.

What is wrong with the second?

Can it be done without repeating the variables twice?

Comment: Every question of the form "This doesn't work" would be greatly improved by providing the following two pieces of information. (1) What did you hope it would do? (2) What did it do instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the first makes (potentially) two comparisons, first comparing `$nis` to `$grp` and, if that fails, comparing `'pre-'.$nis` to `$grp`, while the second will only ever make a single comparison, of `$nis || 'pre-'.$nis` against `$grp`.

Your problem is that `$nis || 'pre-'.$nis` is not a [quantum superposition](http://p3rl.org/Quantum%3a%3aSuperpositions) which can take either value depending on how you look at it, it is a *single* value of either `$nis` *or* `'pre-'.$nis`.  If `$nis` is truthy (which is to say, it is not an empty string, undef, the number 0, or the string "0"), then that value will be `$nis`.  If not, that value will be `'pre-'.$nis` (which, given the truthiness rules, means that `'pre-'.$nis` will only ever be either `'pre-'` or `'pre-0'`).

If you want to compare against two values, you generally need to make two comparisons... but you *can* do this particular comparison in one step by making the value you test against a regular expression:

```
if ($grp =~ /^(:?pre-)?$nis/) {
    print "match3\n";
}
```

I'd stick with the with your first comparison, though, for the sake of readability.

Comment: @daxim: You read my mind... At one point, I had included a link to Q::S myself, but changed my mind at removed it, since it seems to be very much a "not for production use" module, so I would have felt like I had to also include links to/examples of using more "serious" set-handling modules.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong is that "(A or B) equals C" and "(A equals C) or (B equals C)" mean completely different things. In your second `if`, you've asked Perl first to compute `$nis || 'pre-'.$nis` and then to see whether it equals `$grp`.

Computing `$nis || 'pre-'.$nis` (kinda) treats `$nis` and `'pre-'.$nis` as boolean (true/false) values. More precisely, the result equals `$nis` if that's not a value Perl considers "false"; otherwise it equals `'pre-'.$nis`. In this case, `"qqq"` is not false, so the value is just `"qqq"`. Since this doesn't equal `$grp`, the condition in your second `if` is false.

In ordinary language, if you say "Either 3 or 6 is prime" or "Either Joe or Bob is Ellen's brother", a human listener will interpret that in the way I think you want your second `if` to be interpreted. But that's not how any computer language I know of works. (Semi-exception: Grisworld's "Icon".)

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( $grp ~~ [ $nis, "pre-$nis" ] ) {
    print "match\n";
}
```

or (pre-5.10.1)

```
if ( grep $_ eq $grp, $nis, "pre-$nis" ) {
    print "match\n";
}
```

Comment: I'd write the grep solution as `if (grep { $_ eq $grp } ($nis, "pre-$nis"))`, which is clearer, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

($nis || 'pre-' . $nis) evaluates to 'pre-' . $nis only if $nis is either not defined, 0, or an empty string.
so in your case, it's always evaluated as if ($nis eq $grp) { ...
stick with your first approach, and you will be fine

Answer (score 1):

strpos returns the index position of where it first found the $needle, which could be 0. Since 0 also resolves to false the solution is to use strict comparison: if( false !== strpos( $haystack, $needle )...